# Imagens carregadas na ListView ficam trocando aleatoriamente

Tags: java, android

Implementei uma ListView onde é populado uma imagem externa em cada posição, porém quando dou scroll na tela as imagens ficam trocando de forma aleatória.

Este vídeo mostra exatamente o que ocorre: https://vid.me/u1Oc

Obs: não deveria haver nenhuma imagem repetida na ListView.

DownloadTask:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageView;

    public DownloadTask(ImageView thumbnail)
    {
        imageView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        try {
            InputStream strem = new URL(params[0]).openConnection().getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(strem);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ImageView thumbnail = imageView.get();

        if (thumbnail != null)
        {
            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) super.getItem(position);

        if(view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clientes, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.content = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.content);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        new DownloadTask(viewHolder.thumbnail).execute(data.get("thumbnail").toString());

        viewHolder.title.setText(data.get("title").toString());
        viewHolder.content.setText(data.get("content").toString());

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;
        TextView content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode mostrar como está o seu *Adapter*? Acredito que o problema passa por ele.

Comment: Sim, atualizei com o Adapter na descrição.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rafael, esse problema é esperado pela forma como foi implementado.

Você não está fazendo nenhum tratamento para verificar se ao final do download, aquela imagem ainda deve ser mostrada para aquele ImageView.

Isso é devido ao comportamento do ListView de reservar uma quantidade fixas de Views para serem reutilizadas. Logo, você pode ter duas Tasks com a mesma referência para um determinado ImageView.

Para resolver, existem duas formas:

- Usar uma lib para carregamento de imagens, e ai existem dezenas: Picasso, Glide, Universal Image Loader, o próprio Volley, Fresco e etc...

  Acho que é a melhor alternativa, não precisa reinventar a roda, porque você consegue até tratar cache e muitas outras coisas, que é valioso no mundo mobile. E essas libs tem um algoritmo para esse tipo de tratamento de reciclagem do ListView.
- Se for fazer usando o Task, recomendo marcar a View (tag) com alguma chave do Task, porque ao finalizar o Download você pode verificar essa chave e comparar com a chave atual do Task, se for igual, seta o Bitmap normal, senão ignora.

Comment: Utilizei Picasso para o download da imagem, solucionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Bem visto, eu sabia que era por causa do reaproveitamento das *views* mas não me tinha ocorrido o facto do *AsyncTask* poder ter uma referência que já pertence a outra linha.

Comment: Sim, já tive que fazer esse tipo de tratamento porque no meu caso eu tinha uma Task que gerava QRCode e não download de imagens, tive que fazer esse tratamento na mão...